# difficulty with a simple binary adder

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to add 2 binary numbers together using python but i can not figure out how to make a very simple program to do it. This is what i got so far but it is not working:

```
b=input("what number would you like to add ")
convert1= lambda b: str(int(b, 2))

a=input("what number would you like to add to it ")
convert= lambda a: str(int(a, 2))

c=(b+a)
print (c)
convert=lambda c: str(int(c, 2))
print ("Your binary numbers added together is" + convert(c))
```

What i mean by not working is if say i try adding 1001 and 1001 it will say the answer is 10011001. Which is wrong.

Can someone please explain why this is not working and any other simple ways of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Could you post your traceback? Is the expected output different from the actual output?

Comment: Are you using python-3?

Comment: "What i mean by not working is if say i try adding 1001 and 1001 it will say the answer is 10011001" - that's what happens when adding strings.

Comment: Well can someone please tell me how to correct it? and yes python

Comment: I was asking if it was python 3.

Comment: @Bach, it must be python 3, because in Python 2, it prints `2002` instead of `10011001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add 2 strings! Hence the resultant concatenation.

**Edit**: Seems that you want the input to be in binary too.

```
num1 = input("what number would you like to add ")
a = int(num1, 2)

num2 = input("what number would you like to add to it ")
b = int(num2, 2)

ans = bin(a+b)
print("Your addition of numbers, in binary is " + ans)
```

The above would give sum of `10` & `1` as `'0b11'`. But, if you want to only print `'11'`, you would have to use

```
ans = bin(a+b)[2:]
```

Comment: question: Are the users support to input a binary or denary number

Comment: @AhmadNaeem updated now. If the user inputs a denary/decimal number, use `int(num)`, else for binary, use `int(num, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "adding in binary" -- when you add two integers, their base is irrelevant. An integer's *base* is only a convenience when representing it textually. Therefore, what you really want is to add the two integers regularly and *then* convert that result to binary (and perhaps display the two inputs in binary as well). For instance:

```
>>> a = 5  # input 1
>>> b = 3  # input 2
>>> 
>>> bin(a)
'0b101'
>>> bin(b)
'0b11'
>>> 
>>> bin(a + b)
'0b1000'
```

As is, your `a` and `b` are strings, so `c=(b+a)` also produces a string by concatenating `a` and `b`.

If you want to *read* your inputs as binary strings, then you can simply convert them to integers before performing the addition:

```
>>> a = '101'
>>> b = '011'
>>> 
>>> bin(int(a,2) + int(b,2))
'0b1000'
```

Comment: I believe the poster wants the inputs to be in binary format as well, though. So a would be "1001" string and b would be "1001" string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding two strings together; "1001" + "1001" does equal "10011001".

Answer (score 0):

Just use `bin(int())`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin:

```
x = raw_input("what number would you like to add ")
print x,'is',bin(int(x)),'in binary'
y=raw_input("what number would you like to add to it ")
print y, 'is',bin(int(y)),'in binary'
print
print 'their sum in binary is',bin(int(x+y))
```

**[out]:**

```
$ python test.py
what number would you like to add 123
123 is 0b1111011 in binary
what number would you like to add to it 456
456 is 0b111001000 in binary

their sum in binary is 0b11110001001000000
```